# Java Generics Capture List<?>

Tags: java, generics

I was looking at the [Java Generics documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) and found this piece of code,

```
public class WildcardError {

void foo(List<?> l) {
    //This give a compile time error
    l.set(0,l.get(0));
}
}
```

I can understand that we are fetching an element from a `List<?>` and trying to set it to another `List<?>`. So the compiler gives an error. My question is it makes sense when the 2 lists are different i.e. `l.set(0, m.get(0))` here lists `l` and `m` are different. But in the above example, `l` and `l` are the same lists. Why isn't the compiler smart enough to see that? Is it hard to implement it?

**Edit**:
I am aware that I can fix it by a helper method or by using `T` instead of a `?`. Just wondering why compiler doesn't do it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler reports an error because there is no way -- in general -- that it can tell whether two expressions, (in this case `l` and `l`) refer to the same list.

Related, somewhat generalized, question:

- [How does the JLS specify that wildcards cannot be formally used within methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500385/how-does-the-jls-justify-that-wildcards-cannot-be-formally-used-within-methods)

Comment: I've been wondering about a formal reason for this for a long time. I personally feel that this is a lacking feature in the JLS, as the two wild cards in both `l` are formally the same. At least by intuition... But probably, in more complex pieces of code, it would get harder to recognise "identical" wild cards

Comment: Yeah. There are probably some interesting corner cases which would force the spec to be quite complex. Good question though. It's kind of a generalization of this question. You should post it as a follow up.

Comment: OK, this is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500385/how-does-the-jls-justify-that-wildcards-cannot-be-formally-used-within-methods

Comment: Yea. I saw it when you posted it. +1.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I just discoverd a method in the JDK that "suffers" from the same problem... The JDK people resorted to raw types, to circumvent this problem.

Answer (score 9):

In your specific case, you can explicitly fix this:

```
public class WildcardError {
    <T> void foo(List<T> l) {
        // This will work
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to change the original API, introduce a delegate helper method:

```
public class WildcardError {
    void foo(List<?> l) {
        foo0(l);
    }

    private <T> void foo0(List<T> l) {
        // This will work
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler cannot infer that "obvious" `<T>` type. I've been wondering about that, too. It seems like something that could be improved in a compiler, as every wild card can be informally translated to an unknown `<T>` type. Probably, there are some reasons why this was omitted, perhaps this is only intuition, but formally impossible.

**UPDATE**:

Note, I've just seen this peculiar implementation of [`Collections.swap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29):

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

The JDK guys resort to a raw type, in order to handle this, locally. This is a strong statement indicating that this probably *should* be supported by the compiler, but for some reason (e.g. lack of time to formally specify this) just wasn't done

Comment: Yes I am aware of the other alternatives to fix this. Just wondering why compiler can't do that by itself when both lists are the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering about that too. It would've kept me from writing hundreds of useless delegation methods in the past... :-/ Maybe you should update your question and ask for a specific explanation from the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), which explains this.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post :). Where do I get to ask the JLS?

Comment: @vikky.rk: I've re-phrased your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500385/how-does-the-jls-justify-that), to get a more formal answer. Usually, if you're wondering about Java language features, it helps to mention the JLS and request formal explanations

Comment: Thanks. So with the 'JLS' tag, do you expect anyone from JLS to reply? Sorry I am new to SO, so just understanding how it works.

Comment: @vikky.rk: No problem, it takes a bit of practice on SO, to rule out answers that are correct but not what you intended :-) Yours is already pretty good. You will not get answers from Joshua Bloch or Brian Goetz directly, of course. But the more precise your question is, the more precise the answers will be...

Comment: Oh ok. I am new to Java, just exploring the language. So was not sure how to phrase the question correctly.

Answer (score 4):

`List<?>` means *list containing elements of some unknown type*, so when one wants to take elements from it using `list.get(i)` it will return *object of some unknown type*, so the only valid guess will be `Object`. Then when one tries to set element back using `list.set(index, list.get(index))` it produces compile-time error, since as mentioned above `List<?>` can only contain some *unknown type*, so putting `Object` to it may cause `ClassCastException`.

This is explained very well in Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java, 2nd ed., Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility*

This is also known as `PECS` principle and good explanation can be found in this Q/A:
[What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) (please note that `List<?>` is the same as `List<? extends Object>` with minor exceptions)

In laymans terms, one should use `List<?>` as method parameter only to *get elements* from it inside that method, not when one needs to *put elements* into list. When one needs to both *put and get* he/she needs to either generify method using type parameter `T` as in Lukas Eder's answer (type-safe way) or simply use `List<Object>` (not type-safe way).