# Java Map compiler error with generic

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

```
// I know that this method will generated duplicate 
// trim keys for the same value but I am just
// trying to understand why we have a compile error:
// The method put(String, capture#11-of ?) in the type
// Map<String,capture#11-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments
// (String, capture#12-of ?)

void trimKeyMap(Map<String, ?> map){
  for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    map.put(StringUtils.trim(key), map.get(key)); // compile error
  }
}
```

How come the value that we want to put  `map.get(key)` can be from a different type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler only knows the key type is "unknown", but doesn't know it's the *same* unknown type for the type of the Map's key and the type returned from `get()` (even though we as humans realize that it's the same).

If you want to make it work, you must tell the compiler it's the *same* unknown type by *typing* your method, for example:

```
void <V> trimKeyMap(Map<String, V> map) {
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        map.put(StringUtils.trim(key), map.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it is enough to type to a completely unrestricted `V`. This is just to get a handle on the two "unknowns" being the "same unknown".

Answer (score 3):

It might have been possible for the Java 5 expert group, to add a little more power to the specification of wildcards in generic method argument types. I suspect the enhancement didn't make it due to lack of time in the specs phase. See my own recent question here: [How does the JLS specify that wildcards cannot be formally used within methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11500385/521799)

Short of a better solution, you have to make your method a *generic method*:

```
<V> void trimKeyMap(Map<String, V> map){
  for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    map.put(StringUtils.trim(key), map.get(key));
  }
}
```

You cannot put anything in a `Map<String, ?>` type, except for the `null` literal:

```
Map<String, ?> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("A", null); // Works
map.put("B", "X"); // Doesn't work.
```

The compiler doesn't *know* that the map's value argument type was `String`. So it cannot allow you to add anything to the map, even if you got the value from the map itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use type inference in a helper method, if you want to keep the clean method signature (the client of trimKeyMap shouldn't have to use a generic method):

```
void trimKeyMap(final Map<String, ?> map) {
    for (final String key : map.keySet()) {
        trim(map, key);
    }
}

private <T> void trim(final Map<String, T> map, final String key) {
    map.put(StringUtils.trim(key), map.get(key));
}
```

This is called wildcard capture and is discussed more here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04298/

Comment: It's really a shame, though, that javac couldn't generate some ["invisible local generic types"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11500385/521799) to handle this intuitive case of "wildcard capture"

Answer (score 1):

`?` is not a wildcard for *any* type but the *unknown type*. So the map only accepts `?`-type objects and not `String`. One conclusion from this (rather strange) fact: We can't add values to collections that are parametized with `?`.

Answer (score 1):

`?` is different from `Object`.

A `Map<String, ?>` is a generic map where you don't know the element type, but it is still being enforced, i.e. it does not allow you to put anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add values (that are not `null`) to `Collection`s and `Maps` parametrized with a *wildcard* `?`. That is because a *wildcard* is not a substitute for any object, it's just an *unknown* object. So you cannot add any (lets put it that way) known object in a map that accepts only *unknown*.

You can only read values.

Comment: Apparently you can add `null`, but other than that, this answer seems correct.

Comment: Tried to prove you wrong, but failed, so now I agree with you.

Comment: Of course, but I was referring to non-null objects. I had to be more explicit.

Comment: I remembered, that I used <?, ?> declaration several times, but as I learned in the meantime, I'm always reading this variables...