# Java anonymous generic inheritance

Tags: java, generics

Take a look at the next code:

```
ArrayList<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(new Object());
```

It does not compile. The question is why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ArrayList<? extends Object>
```

is the same as just

```
ArrayList<?>
```

and you can assign *any* `ArrayList` to a variable of this type. For example,

```
ArrayList<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is legal. Clearly, the language semantics will not let you add an `Object` to such a list. In fact, they won't let you add *anything at all* to it, except `null`, or something which you directly retrieved from the list.

As noted by Lukas in the comment, it is far from trivial to even add the list's own item back to it: you need a helper method to capture the wildcard into a named type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  addOwn(list);
}
static <T> void addOwn(List<T> l) { l.add(l.get(0)); }
```

Comment: *or something which you directly retrieved from the list.*: That would surprise me. Can you show an example? :-)

Comment: That's cheating ;-) You can of course add `T` to a `List<T>`. But that `List<T>` is no longer a `List<? extends Object>`

Comment: @LukasEder A lot of things with Java Generics can be construed as cheating :) This is a common idiom to solve the use case in question and the point is that you did start with a weakly typed object and managed to upgrade the type.

Comment: I know. I had actually been looking for a formal explanation in the JLS for this, recently: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11500385/521799

Comment: @LukasEder I was fully aware that you knew :)

Comment: Come on. How did you know? ;-)

Comment: Note, here's another "common idiom" to work around that silly limitation of the Java language: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11982573/521799 ;-)

Comment: I'd just note that you never know whether they just lacked the time or hit a brick wall with some edge cases the formal specification of this would have.

Comment: That's why I had asked, back then. Unfortunately, it is hard to get authoritative answers on these matters. Few people remember relevant mailing list threads from 10 years ago. In this case, getting this "feature" correct would just not pull its weight, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is because **Generic types are not polymorphic**. When you use `wildcards ?` with extends you cant add anything in the collection except **null**.

Here is an example to what will happen if that is allowed:

```
Class Car{

}
class A extends Car {

}
class B extends Car{

}
```

Now you have `List<? extends Car>`

```
public void someMethod(List<? extends Car> list){
list.add(new A()); //this is not valid
}
```

Also you may invoke the method like this:

```
List<B> someList = new Array:list<B>(); 
somemethod(someList);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Foo extends Object` does not mean `Collection<Foo>` can be treated as a subtype of `Collection<Object>`. This is simply because the former class does not permit you to do everything the latter does; for instance, you cannot add an `Object` to a `Collection<Foo>`. Using generics instead of some concrete class `Foo` doesn't change this.